# Inconsistencies in st_contains function in R sf package

Tags: r, sf

I am trying to identify, from a set of overlapping buffers, the **smallest** of their intersections. In other words (easier to understand if you look at the picture below), identify amonst all the intersections which are not containing another, smaller, one (the **yellow** one, below). I was very excited to find the st_contains() function in R sf a while ago, but it doesn't work as I thought. 
**Here is a working example**.

```r
> library(sf)
#creating a set of three points
> dfpt<-cbind.data.frame(X=c(328900,328400,331200),Y=c(403000,403400,402300),ID=1:3)
> sfpt<-st_as_sf(dfpt,coords=c('X','Y'))
# creating buffers of 2000m
> sfb<-st_buffer(sfpt,dist=2000)

# intersecting the buffers
> sfint<-st_intersection(sfb,sfb)

# I am interested in two buffers that are embedded
> sfsel<-subset(sfint,(ID==3&ID.1==1)|(ID==3&ID.1==2)) # whether it's ID or ID.1 might change

#check what it looks like
> plot(st_geometry(sfb),col=NA,border='black')
> plot(st_geometry(sfsel[1,]),col='blue',add=TRUE)
> plot(st_geometry(sfsel[2,]),col='yellow',add=TRUE)
```

[image: three buffers and two embedded polygons]

```r
# checking which of the three buffers contain which of the two polygons
> st_contains(sfb,sfsel)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 3, where the predicate was `contains'
 1: 2
 2: (empty)
 3: (empty)
```

(the expected answer should be 1:2, 2:1,2,3:1,2, which I got in other, similar cases)

```
# checking if the two polygons contain each other (the first should contain the second!)
> st_contains(sfsel,sfsel)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 2, where the predicate was `contains'
 1: 1
 2: 2
```

(the expected answer should be 1:1,2, 2:2)

What happens there? I think it might be the approximation of the polygons arcs that lead R to believe the border of the two polygons (blue and yellow above) are not perfectly aligned. I tried to change the scale (by increasing all distances by 1000) and it did improve the function in some cases, but not many. What can I do?

(For info)

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.1                         
year           2019                        
month          07                          
day            05                          
svn rev        76782                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes
```

Answer (score 1):

set a precision, e.g.

```
> st_contains(st_set_precision(sfsel, 1))
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 2, where the predicate was `contains'
 1: 1, 2
 2: 2
```

Comment: Thanks! precision of 1 did not work in some cases, so I tried precision of 0.1. But then I get an error message: Error in CPL_geos_binop(st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y), op, par, pattern,  : 
  Evaluation error: TopologyException: side location conflict at 328590 401410. I am aware this is a non-reproducible example, btw, as I was trying on my full dataset after trying the example (which worked). I can try to make one if it helps.